# problems with vector destructor for vector of shared ptrs

Tags: c++, audio, vector, set, openal

I'm writing a sound manager for sound playback with openal. Each entity in the game is stored as a vector of shared pointers, each entitie  have a private sound object. When each object is defined individually and not put inside the vector, it works flawlessly. However, when putting it in the vector, it looks like they aren't destroyed properly, causing crashes on exit.
I also use a set (static member of the sound class) to keep track of source ids that openal returns for loaded sounds.

```
loaded sounds/boundary.ogg. There are 1 sources. 
loaded sounds/player.ogg. There are 2 sources. 
// at this point, the application plays these sounds properly. 

// on app exit:
destroying sounds/boundary.ogg // deletes the source id for this, should be 1 sources left
there are 0 sources // set is now empty, maybe it got corrupted somehow?
```

Program crashes here. The debugger says that this line in xtree caused the crash:

```
while (!this->_Isnil(_Pnode))
```

If the objects aren't in a vector, the above works without issue. I've also tried using a vector instead of set to store sources, but i get a error indicating the vector got corrupted. Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: Please state the smart pointer type.